# Bad Code Value on chrome with gregwar captcha

Tags: google-chrome, symfony, captcha, symfony-2.3

I have some troubles to make gregwar captcha work on Chrome.
  I have a web app on symphony 2.3 and using gregwar captcha ("dev-master").

I put a captcha on a form.
  And it is working just fine on IE and Firefox.
  But with Chrome, after the form validation, I always get a "Bad Code Value" error.
  And indeed when I looked into `Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Validator\CaptchaValidator.php` on the `compare`function, I really have an `$expectedCode`that is different from `code`.

Any ideas why it's working on both firefox and IE but not in Chrome ?

You can test the page here : http://www.nokachi-lyon.fr/contacts

For information, here is my implementation of Gregwar Captcha :

On `config.yml` I have :

```
gregwar_captcha:
  width: 150
  height: 35
  length: 5
  distortion: false
  invalid_message: "My error message"
```

On `Form` I have :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
  $builder->add('myField','text')
          ->add('captcha', 'captcha');
}
```

On `FormView` I have :

```
{% form_theme form with ['::captcha.html.twig','::formError.html.twig'] %}
<form action="{{ path('club_contacts') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    ...
    {{ form_widget(form.captcha) }}
    ...
</form>
```

On `captcha.html.twig`I have :

```
{% block captcha_widget %}
 <p>My Message :
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <img src="{{ captcha_code }}" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually manage to make it work !
I am not sure to understand why it work now but here is the fix.

In the `Controler`, I used to have something like this :

```
public function contactsAction(Request $request){
    [...]
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        [...]
    }
    return $this->render([...]);
}
```

I changed it to the following :

```
public function contactsAction(Request $request){
    [...]
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        [...]
    }
    return $this->render([...]);
}
```

And now it is working just fine.

Comment: Hi, i have a similar problem i'm using `$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType()); $form->handleRequest($request); if ($form->isValid()) { /* something */ }` and I have the same behavior. So basically I'm using `handleRequest` which is kinda like `bind` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I found my own problem -- I had two separate forms each with a CAPTCHA. The CAPTCHA value was overwritten in the session.